# Double precision in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am using the Fortran 11 compiler in Visual Studio from Windows. How can I set `real` values to `double precision` from project properties? For example, in Fortran Powerstation (4.0) we have the menu option `settings->code generation->default real kind` (here we can set the type of the `real` data type). Similarly, how can we set `double precision` to the `real` variable in the Fortran 11 compiler?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are looking to maintain the code under both compilers, perhaps you would be better off just changing the source code to use real*8's. That would get it behaving consistently when you do ports in the future too.

Comment: Much better to use Fortran properly and specify the kind of your variables as TED suggests.  Even better than REAL*8 would be a standard-compliant way of declaring this, REAL(KIND=KIND(1d0)), or, for extra portability and future proofness REAL(KIND=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(x,y)) -- but you have to figure out x and y for your program.

Comment: I agree. REAL*8 isn't portable, but processor and compiler dependent. Using KIND is the way it should be done if portability is needed.

Answer (score 1):

One other way around is using module *iso_fortran_env*. Then you can specify the real kind with predefined variables *REAL32, REAL64* and *REAL128*, which are single precision, double precision and quadruple precision, if your compiler supports.

For example:

```
program main

    use iso_fortran_env

    implicit none

    real(real32)  :: a1 ! single precision
    real(real64)  :: a2 ! double precision
    real(real128) :: a4 ! quadruple precision

end program
```

Comment: `real(real64)` doesn't mean "a double precision real",or `double precision`, just,if supported, a real with 64-bit storage size.

Comment: Definitely won't work in MS Powerstation. But maybe it is not needed. Who knows at such an old question. But the point should be to suggest to uso some  kind constants at all. Not where to get their values. That is secondary IMHO. This does not answer the original question almost at all.

Comment: `real(real64)` is the same as double precision, I have used a polymorphic variable and when you pass a double precision number, it will be captured by `real(real64)`.

Comment: @Zeus only with some compilers. Only in certain settings. Common and often default settings. But they do not mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the project properties to achieve this.

Open the Project Properties Dialog then navigate to ConfigurationProperties->Fortran->Data.

Then choose the drop down beside Default Real KIND and choose "8(/real)size64).

I am sure this is valid from VS2012 and on.